# Necesito enviar dos objetos a un web service para que me responda en swift

Tags: ajax, swift3, aplicación-web

Estoy realizando una aplicación en swift 3 xcode 8 y me dicen que para que yo pueda acceder al web service necesito enviar dos objetos, me manda el siguiente ejemplo en ajax, ¿cómo lo puedo hacer con xcode 8?

```
$("#cargar").click(function() {

    /*datosRegistro = {
        'user'      :   $("#user").val(),
        'pass'      :   $("#pass").val()
    };*/

    Datos = {
        "usr_username"  :   "usuario",
        "usr_password"  :   "contrasenia"    
    };

    datosRegistro = {
        "Accion"    :   2 , //2  es obligatorio para login
        "Datos"     :   Datos   
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://mihost/server/sitio.php',
        data: {'datosRegistro': JSON.stringify(datosRegistro) },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(p, estado, xhr) {
            // Para atrapar otros posibles errores
            try {
                // Asigna el objeto de retorno
                objRetorno = JSON.parse(p);

                // Valida el error controlado
                if ( objRetorno.Error == true ) {
                    // Informa el error al usuario
                    // Muestra el mensaje (cambia icono y pone mensaje)
                    alert(objRetorno.Mensaje);

                    // Termina el procedimiento
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {

                    //aqui escribes el codigo en caso de ser correctos los datos

                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch(error){
                // Notifica el error al usuario
                alert( "Excepcion encontrada al recuperar cadena JSON.\n\nDetalles : " + error.message ) ;
            }  

        },
        error: function(xhr, estado, errata) {
            // Informa el error interno al usuario
            alert('La accion no pudo ser procesada correctamente...');

            // Termina el procedimiento
            return false;
        },
        dataType:   'html'

    }); // Termina la llamada AJAX
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más seguro es que tengas una URL a la que hacer la petición como por ejemplo

http://webservice.com/file.php y aquí tengas que construir la cadena con los parámetros que te pidan pero te tienen que decir los administradores cómo pasarlos.

Si por ejemplo le estás pasando Id pero ellos en su webservice lo están intentando validar como iduser te va a fallar.

La URL tendrás que construirla como por ejemplo: http://webservice.com/file.php?id=1234&clave=2345 (te aconsejaría pasar las variables en minúscula, en vez de Id como tienes pasar id). De todas formas tendrás que pedirles como comentaba el compañero cómo tienes que facilitarles los datos: si ellos buscan una variable por nombre "idusuario" y le pasas "id" siempre va a fallar, pero es algo que te tienen que aclarar ellos ;)

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

> ... me dicen que para que yo pueda acceder al web service necesito enviar dos objetos

**EDIT:**

*Modifico la pregunta ampliando algunos detalles.*

**(a). EL WEB SERVICE**

Swift envía una petición al web service a través de una URL y  éste te devuelve el JSON. Al recibirlo lo tratas (parsear) en Swift, como se explica en **(b).**

Para que el web service te devuelva por ejemplo esto:

```
{
        "usr_username"  :   "victor.ramirez",
        "usr_password"  :   "victor"    
    }
```

Debes saber cómo construir tu URL, eso te lo dirá quien gestione el web service. En el caso tuyo, un ejemplo (imaginario) de URL sería:

```
http://sipot.conanp.gob.mx/server/pasaportes.php?id=878&otro=otroparametro
```

Como ves envías dos parámetros al web service separados por &, él lo recibe y los usa para consultar los datos que quieres y te devuelve un JSON correcto y si no otro erróneo.

Incluso puedes probar si el web service devuelve lo que esperas, poniendo la URL en cualquier navegador. Si  escribes en tu navegador algo como esto: `https://reqres.in/api/users/1` obtendrás este resultado que podrás ver en pantalla:

```
    {
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "george",
        "last_name": "bluth",
        "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
    }
}
```

Fíjate en la elegancia de la URL. A través de ella lo que se le pide al web service es que te de los datos del usuario cuyo id=1.

En tu caso, una URL elegante o amigable sería: `http://sipot.conanp.gob.mx/server/pasaportes/usuario/878` en la que le pides los datos de pasaporte del usuario cuyo id=878. Pero como dije antes, esto depende del programador del web service. Lo importante es que este funcione bien, mande los datos que pides y te toca a ti procesarlos.

**(b). Manejar los datos recibidos desde el web service (o api) en Swift**

Recibidos tus datos, en este caso un JSON, lo manejas en Swift. En este ejemplo el JSON es almacenado dentro de  la variable `parsedData`.

Ejemplo:

```
let urlString = "http://tu.url.com"

let url = URL(string: urlString)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
  if error != nil {
    print(error)
  } else {
    do {

      let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
      let usrName= parsedData["usr_username"] as! [String:Any]

      print(usrName)

      let usrPassword = parsedData["usr_password"] as! [String:Any]
      print(usrPassword)
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print(error)
    }
  }

}.resume()
```

Esto puede serte muy útil: [Ayuda de Apple sobre Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37)

Comment: Cuando hago la solicitud el web service me responde:

{"Error":true,"Mensaje":"estas intentando hackearnos, o no enviaste la informacion de forma correcta","Cuenta":0,"Datos":null}

y el encargado del web service me dice que me responde eso debido a que no le estoy mandando datos y no se los estoy mandando bien. Por lo tanto, no sé como hacerle en swift, me dice que tengo que mandar objetos como los que mencioné anteriormente. Pero no sé si eso se pueda hacer con swift. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: He dividido la respuesta en dos partes (a y b), creo que está bastante clara. Pregúntale al encargado del web service cómo tienes que mandar tu consulta, que te de un ejemplo con una URL construida. Si es para probar tu código, cualquier url QUE FUNCIONE te sirve, por ejemplo esta: `https://reqres.in/api/users/1` si la escribes en tu navegador de devuelve un JSON que  puedes usar para probar tu aplicación.

Comment: Muchas por tu ayuda!!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando hago la solicitud el web service me responde:

{"Error":true,"Mensaje":"estas intentando hackearnos, o no enviaste la informacion de forma correcta","Cuenta":0,"Datos":null}

y el encargado del web service me dice que me responde eso debido a que no le estoy mandando datos y no se los estoy mandando bien. Por lo tanto, no sé como hacerle en swift, me dice que tengo que mandar objetos como los que mencioné anteriormente. Pero no sé si eso se pueda hacer con swift. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: En lugar de escribir otra respuesta era mejor comentar la  anterior.  La forma de consultar al web service la establece el programador del mismo. Si en este caso no eres tú debes decir al encargado que te de un ejemplo sobre cómo debes hacer la consulta, es decir, sobre cómo debes construir tu URL, que parámetros debes poner en ella. De todos modos el web service  está devolviendo un JSON con un mensaje de error, es una posibilidad que debes incluir en la lógica de tu programa. O sea, así como buscas el nombre de usuario u otros  en el JSON deberías buscar si hay en el mismo un  elemento Error

Comment: muchas gracias por su respuesta me han ayudado mucho